# Eclipse not launching

Tags: eclipse

I'm working on an iMac(OS 10.8.2) and when I launch Eclipse, the splash screen just hangs. I've installed the latest Java release 7, update 15 hoping that might solve the problem but it didn't.

Any help appreciated.

Regards,
Stephen

Comment: Any stacktrace in the eclipse log files?

Comment: Try running it from the shell to see if you get any errors, e.g. /Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse

Comment: Can you go to installation directory and try `eclipse -clean`? If that will not work, re-installing Eclipse should solve your problem.

Comment: @arin Thanks, I had to reinstall it. It you put this as an answer, I'll mark it accordingly.

Comment: If the problem should pop up again sometime, I would recommend you look into the log files. I have a reoccuring problem with the Git Plugin, that will not let me launch eclipse even with `-clean`, but is relatively simple to work around, and certainly preferable to reinstalling Eclipse. Even after reinstall you cannot be sure that the problem does not pop up again.

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment was able to help out, I am posting it as an answer:

> Please try `eclipse -clean` from the installation directory. If that doesn't work, re-installing Eclipse should solve your problem.